# Find USB Host Path in android?

Tags: android

I need to connect and disconnect usb progrmmatically , that is in android device, i have connected the usb device via usb cable. I need to transfer the file from android device to usb device, the application will watch the particular folder and transfer the file from that folder to usb drive. I need to disconnect the usb after the file is transfered and connect the usb when needed.

Please guide me with code.

Thanks in Advance....